# About using onto and into in the definition of automorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

Definition. An isomorphism $\phi: G \to G$ of a group $G$ with itself is an automorphism of G.

Why is it that rephrasing this definition with "An automorphism of a group G is an isomorphism mapping $G$ into $G$" is incorrect while
"An automorphism of a group G is an isomorphism mapping $G$ onto $G$" is correct?

Does 'into' pertains to injectivity in the former case and 'onto' means surjectivity in the latter one? But is it not enough to include the term 'isomorphism' to mean that the mapping is both injective and surjective?

Comment: Writing $G'$ is confusing, just write $G$.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for pointing out. I should have written $G$ to avoid confusion, but my question remains.

Comment: It is useful to divide this into two parts. First, $\phi$ is a endomomorphism, so a homomorphism from $G$ to itself (and not to some other group $G'$). Here "to" is enough, you wrote "into", which means the same.  Secondly, $\phi$ is bijective. This way "into" or "onto" is not used. So a bijective endomorphism is an automorphism of $G$.

Comment: Shouldn't we say "surjective endomorphism" since endomorphism means injective homomorphism?

Comment: No, endomorphism only means a homomorphism "to itself" (endo). So from $G$ to $G$ and not to some other group $G'$ like you did. Therefore we have to say **bijective** in addition in the second step. This includes then injective and surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think either variant, "mapping $G$ into $G$: or "mapping $G$ onto $G$" is good/correct. Simply "isomorphism of $G$ to $G$". This includes, quite explicitly, both injectivity and surjectivity.

Sometimes people accidentally blur the distinctions between the mathematical and colloquial senses of "to", "onto", "into", etc. It is more reliable to use "injective", "surjective", and "bijective", since these have no colloquial senses. :)